# Desktop items not showing because of compiz live wallpaper

Tags: compiz, desktop-background, live-environment

I have installed compiz live wallpaper. It works fine but it doesn't show my desktop items. I have to open my home folder and then access them in the ~/Desktop folder.

How can I get my desktop to show the files and folders?